# wordpress navigation. Not show submenu only li

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I create a customized wordpress menu but when I place a submenu in the admin panel, it does not appear. I'm using the bootstrap menu for the mobile version. The submenu should be generated as ul-tag in li-tag but not. Maybe there is some function.

header.php

```
 <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="navDiv">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <ul id="nav" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                            <li><?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu',
                                    'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) );?></li>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

function.php

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'my-custom-menu' => __( 'My Custom Menu' ),
        'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
);
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to create a menu is this:

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'my-custom-menu' => __( 'My Custom Menu', 'domain' ),
            'extra-menu'     => __( 'Extra Menu', 'domain' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```